# Does SneakyThrows actually stop an exception from propagating?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
  @SneakyThrows
  public void startDatabase() throws NotBoundException, RemoteException {
    entityRepository = new EntityRepositoryImpl(DatabaseManagerImpl.getInstance());
    registrar = new RegistrarImpl(entityRepository);
    String process = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    registrar.register();
    LOG.debug("Started database with process id: " + process);
  }
```

In which it throws an exception `NotBoundException, RemoteException` adding the `@SneakyThrows` annotation makes the IDE report that both these two exceptions are not thrown by the method (anymore).

Does Lombok SneakyThrows actually stop an exception from propagating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not prevent the exception from propagating.

> @SneakyThrows can be used to sneakily throw checked exceptions without actually declaring this in your method's throws clause.

Reference: https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows